# Use macros or visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2013, basic

I have three names in column c in excel and 50 numbers in column a I want to assign names equally in column b using loop. I used recorded macros to get the name in column b but it is not working when there is more or less value in column c

Comment: it's unclear for me. what you mean by assign names equally

Comment: Please post some code and some output

Comment: Actually I want to assign the work to the associates. There is works in column a and name of associates in column c. I want to assign the work equally to associates

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually.

Copy these three names two times into the column B. Select these six cells
and drag & fill (using the small black square on bottom right - 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db )

Comment: It won't work when the number of value increase or decrease in column c. My friend used two loops to solve the issue